# Объединить вызов двух функций jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для одного и того же элемента `.form-field-2` выполняется один и тот же набор действий при `blur` и при `keypress` и `keyup`. 
Можно ли как-то вынести набор вызываемых действий в отдельный блок или объединить вызов функции?

```
$('.form-field-2').blur(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.edit-task').css("display", "none");
    $(this).closest('li').find('.show-task').css("display", "block").find('label').html(value);
});

$('.form-field-2').bind('keypress keyup', (function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest('.edit-task').css("display", "none");
        $(this).closest('li').find('.show-task').css("display", "block").find('.show-task label').html(value);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общие действия можно вынести в функцию и вызывать её в каждом обработчике:

```
function doSth() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.edit-task').css("display", "none");
    $(this).closest('li').find('.show-task').css("display", "block").find('label').html(value);
}

$('.form-field-2').blur(function () {
    doSth.call(this);
});

$('.form-field-2').keypress(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        doSth.call(this);
    }
});
```

Здесь используется вызов функции через `call` для того, чтобы функция выполнялась в контексте нужного объекта (то есть, чтобы `this` внутри функции был таким, каким надо нам). Можно вызывать функцию и без этого, но тогда придётся передавать `this` в качестве аргумента:

```
function doSth(_this) {
    var value = $(_this).val();
    $(_this).closest('.edit-task').css("display", "none");
    $(_this).closest('li').find('.show-task').css("display", "block").find('label').html(value);
}
```

В этом случае обработчик будет выглядеть так:

```
$('.form-field-2').blur(function () {
    doSth(this);
});
```

Документация по `this` и `call`:

http://javascript.ru/Function/call

http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/thiskeyword

Comment: Спасибо, работает!